# Improve running speed for DeleteDuplicates

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, filtering

How to make this faster? I want to remove elements that satisfy the condition below but it's way too slow.

```
tup1 = Tuples[{{0, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0, 
     1}, {-1, 0, 1}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0, 
     1}, {-1, 0, 1}}];
tup2 = DeleteDuplicates[
   tup1, (#1[[1 ;; 3]] == #2[[4 ;; 
          6]]) && (#1[[4 ;; 6]] == #2[[1 ;; 3]] && #1[[7 ;; 
           9]] == #2[[10 ;; 12]]) && (#1[[10 ;; 12]] == #2[[7 ;; 
          9]]) &];
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a semi-imperative way that gives the same result as `tup2` from the original question, but much faster:

```
tup2b = Module[{keep}
, keep[t_] :=
    ( keep[t] = False
    ; keep[t[[{4,5,6,1,2,3,10,11,12,7,8,9}]]] = False
    ; True
    )
; Select[tup1, keep]
];

tup2b === tup2
(* True *)

Length[tup2b] === Length[tup2] === 52650
(* True *)
```

On my machine, the calculation of `tup2` takes a couple of hours whereas the approach shown here is subsecond.  This approach also makes it easy to add other equivalence criteria if desired.

**How It Works**

The function `keep` is used as a predicate to `Select` to determine whether to keep each entry of the list.  The first time each element is encountered, `keep` returns `True`.  But as a side-effect it also adds a new definition to `keep` that records that the entry and its equivalent permutation are no longer to be kept.  The new definition will return `False` if either entry is encountered later in the list.  In this way `keep` effectively maintains a set of entries seen so far (along with their equivalents).

For the example list given in the question, it is not strictly necessary to record that we have seen each unpermuted entry since there are no duplicates.  But in the general case that might not be so.

This method scans each entry of the list once, so it runs in time roughly proportional to the length $n$ of the list.  Technically, the time is more on the order of $n \ln(n)$ due to the hashing involved in saving and testing entries, but for small $n$ the difference is not that noticeable.

By contrast, and as [Leonid Shifrin](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/237681/improve-running-speed-for-deleteduplicates/237697?noredirect=1#comment600638_237697) points out, `DeleteDuplicates` must in principle compare every *pair* of elements, so the run time is proportional to $n^2$ -- a *much* larger number of iterations.

Comment: wondering if [`Pick`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html) might be slightly more readable here.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform It is probably just a matter of taste, but I think I prefer the `Select` form over something like `Pick[tup1, keep /@ tup1]`.

Comment: Sure, it is definitely a matter of taste. My point was that `Pick` together with a minor modification of `keep` might be ever so slightly cleaner/more readable. Or using the third argument. Or, being optimistic, perhaps there is a way to avoid having to define `keep` altogether. But I'm really just thinking out loud so don't take me too seriously :-)

Comment: +1. It might be worth mentioning that `DeleteDuplicates` with explicit predicate uses quadratic complexity algorithm based on pairwise comparisons, which explains the timing difference, as well as the existence of `DeleteDuplicatesBy` as a separate function.

Comment: This is pretty fast. Could you explain a bit about the algorithm?

Comment: I have added the new section _How It Works_.  (also @LeonidShifrin)

Answer (score 10):

You can also get `tup2` from `tup1` using:

#### 1. [`Union`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Union.html)

```
ClearAll[fA]
fA = Union[Sort[{#, #[[{4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 7, 8,  9}]]}] & /@ #][[All, 1]] &;

tup2A = fA @ tup1; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.213222
> ```

```
Length @ tup2A
```

> ```
> 52650
> ```

#### 2.  [`DeleteDuplicates`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicates.html)

```
ClearAll[fB]
fB = DeleteDuplicates[
 Sort[{#, #[[{4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 7, 8, 9}]]}] & /@ #][[All, 1]] &;

tup2B = fB @ tup1; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.257217
> ```

#### 3. [`GroupOrbits`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupOrbits.html) + [`PermutationGroup`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PermutationGroup.html)

```
ClearAll[fC]
fC = GroupOrbits[PermutationGroup[{{4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 7, 8, 9}}], #, 
    Permute][[All, 1]] &

tup2C = fC @ tup1; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.640413
> ```

#### 4.  Memoization

```
ClearAll[fD]
fD = Module[{f0}, 
  f0[x_] := (f0[x] = f0[x[[{4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 7, 8, 9}]]] = Sequence[]; x); 
    f0 /@ #] &;

tup2D = fD @ tup1; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.794055
> ```

#### 5. [`DeleteDuplicatesBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicatesBy.html)

```
ClearAll[fE]
fE = DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort[{#, #[[{4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 7, 8, 9}]]}]&]

tup2E = fE @ tup1; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 1.13389
> ```

#### 6. [`GroupBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html)

```
ClearAll[fF]
fF = Values @ GroupBy[#, 
     Sort[{#, #[[{4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 7, 8, 9}]]}] &, 
     First] &;

tup2F = fF @ tup1; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 1.28655
> ```

All six results match `tup2b` from WReach's answer:

```
tup2b == tup2A == tup2B == tup2C == tup2D == tup2E == tup2F
```

> ```
> True
> ```

In comparison, `tup2b` takes about a second:

```
tup2b = Module[{keep}, 
     keep[t_] := (keep[t] = False; 
       keep[t[[{4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 7, 8, 9}]]] = False; 
       True); Select[tup1, keep]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 1.06063
> ```

Answer (score 7):

A tuple is deleted if **both** its first two triples **and** its second two triples are identical when exchanged (but not when they're the same when not swapped). That we can construct the undeleted tuples directly like so:

```
tup2 =
  Module[{
    pair = Tuples[Tuples[{{0, 1}, {0, -1, 1}, {0, -1, 1}}], 2],
    unique
    },
   
   unique = DeleteDuplicates[pair, #1 === Reverse@#2 &];
   
   Flatten /@ 
    DeleteDuplicates@
     Join[Tuples[{unique, pair}], Tuples[{pair, unique}]]];
```

Takes about a tenth of a second on my laptop.

---

**UPDATE**: If you want to use the existing `tup1` and delete the duplicates, you can keep the ones that appear in `tup2` like so:

```
tup3 = Intersection[tup1, tup2];
```

which is very fast. If for some reason you need to keep `tup1` in the original order, you can do something a bit slower:

```
tup4 = Select[tup1, AssociationThread[tup2 -> True]];
```

This takes another 0.2 seconds on my laptop.

Given the way the problem is stated, it's much easier to construct tuples you know are unique than to delete duplicates after the fact.

Comment: I don't get this. Your `pair` structure is different from mine. Can this method be used if I already have `tup1` as above?